# how to add an custom html in Angular app or dynamically load an other component?

Tags: angular, datatables-1.10

I have embedded an DataTables in an Angular component. Table is rendered correctly, but now I want to add an button and after click I want to  execute an method in my controller.

How can I dynamically create the html in the table cell that the Angular binding (click etc) will be working?

```
{
   data: null, searchable: false, orderable: false,
   render: (data, type, full) => {
        return '<button class="test" (click)="showDetails($event)">Details</button>';
   }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Or how can I dynamically inject an other component with this button and bind data to it?

Comment: Create and insert components dynamically is not a simple task. Are you sure you cant just use a list of predefined templates for this?

Comment: Can you show me any example to get the point on your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Example of the component that displays different data depending on its type:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="type"

    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="TYPE.T_INTEGER">
        <span *ngIf="v != null" [style.white-space]="pre ? 'pre' : null">{{v}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="v == null" style="color:#ccc">Not set</span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="TYPE.T_STRING">
        <span *ngIf="v != null" style="white-space: pre">{{v}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="v == null" style="color:#ccc">Not set</span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="TYPE.T_BOOLEAN">
        <div [style.color]="v ? '#00aa00' : '#990000'">
            <i style="line-height:1;font-size:1.25rem" [ngClass]="v ? 'fa-check' : 'fa-cancel'"></i>
            <span style="position:relative;top:-.313rem">{{v ? 'true' : 'false'}}</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="TYPE.T_STRING_ARRAY">
        <ng-template [ngIf]="v != null">
            <span class="layout vertical" style="text-align:left">
                <small *ngFor="let l of v" style="font-weight:bold">{{l}}</small>
            </span>
        </ng-template>
        <span *ngIf="v == null" style="color:#ccc">Not set</span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ngSwitchDefault>
        <div class="layout vertical end">
            <small style="color:#900">unhandled type: {{type}}</small>
            <pre style="margin:0;color:inherit;max-width:700px;max-height:500px;text-align:left;overflow:auto">{{value | json}}</pre>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

</div>
```